# Import [insert or update] Excel/CSV to MySQL database using maatwebsite in laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, insert-update, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

While importing/uploading an excel file, if the data is already present in the excel file then update it in the Database or else insert it. This means before inserting should check with the database. So, anyone please help to solve with this issue:

**This is the Import class for customers:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Customer;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;

class ImportCustomers implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithValidation
{
    use Importable;
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */

    public function model(array $row)
    {

        // Check mobile already exists
       /* $count = Customer::where('mobile',$row['mobile'])->count();
       dd($count);
       if($count > 0){
          return null;
       } */
        return new Customer([
            'customer_name' => $row['customer_name'],
            'mobile' => $row['mobile'],
            'email' => $row['email']
        ]);
    }

    

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
             '*.customer_name' => 'required',
             '*.mobile' => 'required|unique:customers',
             '*.email' => 'required',

        ];
    }
}
```

---

/* This is Controller:*/

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\CustomerImportRequest;
use App\Imports\ImportCustomers;
use App\Exports\ExportCustomers;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use DB;
use App\Customer;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

class ImportExportExcelController extends Controller
{
    protected $customers;

    public function __construct(Customer $customers){
        $this->customers = $customers;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $customers = $this->customers->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
        return view('ImportExportExcel', compact('customers'));
    }

    public function importExcel(CustomerImportRequest $request)
    {
        try {

            if ($request->hasFile('import_file')) 
            {
                $file = $request->file('import_file');
                $columnRead = (new ImportCustomers)->toArray($file);
                
                
                $customerCheck = $this->customers->where('mobile',$columnRead[0][1]["mobile"])->first(); //**here not getting result, rather shows null**
                //dd($customerCheck);
                if($customerCheck)
                {
                    $customers = $customerCheck;
                    /* 
                    **How to update if duplicates are found and display old values updated. How to achieve this?**
                    */

                }else{
                    $customers = new $this->customers;
                    Excel::import(new ImportCustomers, $file);

                    return redirect()->back()->with('success','Data imported successfully.');
                }
                
            }

        } catch (\Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\ValidationException $e) {
             $failures = $e->failures();
             //dd($failures);
             return redirect()->back()->with('import_errors', $failures);
             
        }
        
        
    }

    public function exportExcel()
    {
        $customers = Customer::select(["customer_name", "mobile", "email"])->get();  
        return Excel::download(new ExportCustomers($customers), 'customers.xlsx');
    }
}
```

---

/*This is the database migration schema:*/

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('customer_name');
            $table->string('mobile', 13)->unique();
            $table->string('email')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Here "mobile" is unique, So if values like customer_name, and email are with modified values in an excel sheet with the same mobile no. then while importing, values should be updated.
[excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8WAx.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have used maatwebsite with Laravel 6

Controller :

```
Excel::import(new ImportCustomers(), $file);
```

then you could apply your logic at the Import class for customers:

```
public function model(array $row)
{
try {
    $mobile =  $row[1]; //  referenced by row 
    $customer_name =  $row[0];
    $email = $row[1];
    $customer = Customer::where('mobile', $mobile)->first();
    //apply your logic
    if (!$customer) { // you may not need if else, if no customer exists then create a new record and assign mobile
        $customer = new Customer();
        $customer->mobile = $mobile;
    }
    $customer->customer_name = $customer_name;
    $customer->email = $email;        
    $customer->save();
    return $customer;
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    dd($ex);
    return;
}
}
```

Also please remove the rule about mobile, I think this should work

```
"*.mobile' => 'required',"
```

because your logic handles that mobile is unique.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Here now record importing for the first time is working but again if we upload the same, Displaying alert like - The mobile has already been taken.

Comment: Please remove the rule about mobile, I think this should work "*.mobile' => 'required'," because your logic handles that mobile is unique.

Comment: I am glad to hear it, I have already fixed my answer, if you find it now correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Check for the existing value in database and if result is found do this.
 public function model(array $row)
    {

        // Check mobile already exists
        $count = Customer::where('mobile',$row['mobile'])->first();
       
       if($count){
          return;
       } 
    else{
        return new Customer([
            'customer_name' => $row['customer_name'],
            'mobile' => $row['mobile'],
            'email' => $row['email']
        ]);
       }
    }
```